# Spring cloud sleuth 3.0.1 generate traceid & spanid in logs using logback

Tags: java, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am using `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:3.0.1` and `spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:3.0.1` to generate `traceId` and `spanId` in log file. I was able to get those in logs using `2.2.7.RELEASE` version. I have tried using `logback` but not able to have with `3.0.1` version. As per 3.0.1 documentation, they have removed Legacy MDC entries but brave `spanId` & `traceId` are there.

Dependency hierarchy:
[image: Dependency_hierarchy]

traceId & spanId are not generated in log:

[image: Log]

I have tried to see this request's tracing on zipkin and able to see it with traceid and spanid:

[image: zipkin]

Can anyone help me to get traceid and spanid in log file using logback/log4j?

Answer (score 0):

Sleuth does this for you by default in 3.x too: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-log-integration

You can break this functionality by misconfiguring your log pattern or `logging.pattern.level` or your classpath.

What I would suggest is going to https://start.spring.io, generate a new project using sleuth and web/webflux, write a single controller and check the logs (do not create any log config file, just leave everything on default).